# Getting Too Deeply Nested Error when trying to add a list to a footnote that is within a list

Tags: footnotes, enumitem

I am in a situation where I need to use custom lists and I don't know how to resolve this error. Also got the extra/missing } error but I can't seem to find it!

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem} 
\setlist{parsep=0pt,listparindent=\parindent}
\setlist[enumerate, 2]{leftmargin=0cm}

\newlist{mylist3}{itemize*}{1}
\setlist[mylist3]{label=-}

\begin{document}
List of entries:
        \begin{mylist3}
            \item[] Entry 1
            \item   Entry 2
            \footnote{
                List of entries :
                \begin{mylist3}
                    \item[] Entry 1
                    \item   Entry 2
                    \item   Entry 3
                    \item   Entry 4
                \end{mylist3}
                }
            \item   Entry 3
            \item   Entry 4
        \end{mylist3}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Just to sure, do you want the footnote to have a list in it?

Comment: Yes. In my main document the items in the list are quite long in the footnote so I trimmed down it here in the example. (I know that I don't need to use lists but there are so much formatting in my document that it would be confusing not to.)

Comment: It works if you duplicate your newlist (and setlist) definition (call the second one `mylist3sub`, for example). Then use that for the nested list. The footnote isn't the problem - it's the nesting of your new list inside itself that created the error. I don't have a great explanation for that, so I won't put this as a full answer, but hopefully this does what you need.

Answer (score 4):

Your footnote list is nested inside another list of the same type and you have declared that this list only has one level. Just define it with two levels.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem} 
\setlist{parsep=0pt,listparindent=\parindent}
\setlist[enumerate, 2]{leftmargin=0cm}

\newlist{mylist3}{itemize*}{2}
\setlist[mylist3]{label=-}

\setlength{\textheight}{2cm} % just for the example

\begin{document}
List of entries:
        \begin{mylist3}
            \item[] Entry 1
            \item   Entry 2% <--- NEEDED
            \footnote{% <--- NEEDED
                List of entries:
                \begin{mylist3}
                    \item[] Entry 1
                    \item   Entry 2
                    \item   Entry 3
                    \item   Entry 4
                \end{mylist3}% <--- NEEDED
                }
            \item   Entry 3
            \item   Entry 4
        \end{mylist3}
\end{document}
```

[image]